# How do you disable DHCP in VMWare Player?

Tags: dhcp, vmware-player

VMWare Player seems to have a DHCP server built into it that automatically runs on the "Host-Only" networks and provides addresses to the clients.

Is there some way that I can disable this DHCP service and make those networks just act like a dumb switch?  I want to handle DHCP requests on the host.

I see the option for "Lan Segments" but can't seem to make those available to the host OS.

Comment: I replied a minute ago based on Workstation's menu. Found a Player around here but I cannot find the same option to edit virtual networks.

Answer (score 1):

I found that you can simply disable the "VMWare DHCP Service" under services on Windows (I'm sure there is a Linux equivalent).  However that will disable DHCP for *all* VMs, not just the one you are interested in.

It would be great if there were a way to configure it per VM.

Answer (score 0):

solution for vmware player 4.03 in ubuntu 9.10
in a terminal run :
sudo gedit /etc/vmware/vmnet8/dhcpd/dhcpd.conf

place "#" on each line

reboot or restart vmware services

it works